# <g:remoteFunction> in grails

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

i have this Jquery code :

```
 $(".inputFiles").on("change", function(e) {
    var uploadedFiles = e.originalEvent.target.files;
    var fileSize = 100;
    var fileType = ["image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg"];

    alert("length" + uploadedFiles.length)
    for (var i = 0,len = uploadedFiles.length; i < len; i++) {
        var n = uploadedFiles[i].name;
        var s = uploadedFiles[i].size; 
        var t = uploadedFiles[i].type;


                    }
 <g:remoteFunction action="testAjax" params="[files:uploadedFiles]" />
     });

   });
```

and here is the action in the controller :

```
def testAjax() {
    println ("ajax data "+params)
    }
```

i'm always getting `params.files` null ,although `alert("length" + uploadedFiles.length)` is showing the numbers of uploaded files , and also i want to update `<p id="msgs"/>` in case of success or failure .

i also tired the below rather `<g:remoteFunction action="testAjax" params="[files:uploadedFiles]" />`  , but it's not reaching the action `testAjax` , how i can fix it

```
$.ajax({ 
        url:'/myApp/photos/testAjax',
        type:'POST' ,
        dataType: 'JSON', 
        data: {files: uploadedFiles}, 
        success: function(data) {
        alert ("all files uploaded" + data);
            },

        error: function(data,textStatus) {alert("something went wrong " + textStatus);},
        complete : function (){
        alert("all done fine");
            }

        });
```

Comment: try to add controller name, mb it is not in directory of your controller

Comment: @RomanRomanovsky , i added the controller , but still the same result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass javascript variable to grails controller using remoteFunction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389908/how-can-i-pass-javascript-variable-to-grails-controller-using-remotefunction)

Comment: You can not call a JavaScript variable from the tag in that way. Check the question in the last comment.

Comment: @quindimildev , ya it worked ,but as it was deprecated ,so i'll use `$.ajax({})` , but it 's not reaching my action !! , is there something wrong in the syntax ?

Comment: are you using spring security or something like that ?

Comment: @quindimildev    ya i'm using spring security , do i need to configure something ?

Comment: you have to check if the current user has privileges to post to the action. Use the browser debugger to see what is the error. If you get a 403 error "forbiden" means ajax (user) is not allowed to access to the action.

Comment: Was spring security config the throuble?

Answer (score 0):

In your example output in data will be like:

```
data: {'files':'uploadedFiles'}
```

Because:

```
if(attrs?.params instanceof Map) {
                    hasParams = true
                    out << attrs.remove('params').collect { k, v ->
                        "\'" +
                                "${k}".encodeAsJavaScript() +
                                "\': \'" +
                                "${v}".encodeAsJavaScript() +
                                "\'"
                    }.join(",")
                }
```

here is part of code from remoteFunction taglib.
The best way for you is write your own ajax code:
If you send files it will be post, so:

```
$.post("${createLink(action: 'testAjax', absolute:true)}", {files:uploadedFiles})
```

I think it more easier and more clean.
Hope it was helpful.

Comment: i tried `$.post("${createLink(action: 'testAjax', absolute:true)}", {files:uploadedFiles})` it's not even calling the action

Comment: it can be helpful http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the JQuery as the javascript library. Then you can try this

```
<g:remoteFunction action="testAjax" params="'files':uploadedFiles" />
```

If you are using Dojo, you can try this:

```
<g:remoteFunction action="testAjax" params="'files'=uploadedFiles" />
```

The underlying trick is to read the source code in browser's developer's tool to see Grails' translation to javascript is right or wrong; then adjust the code according to the translated javascript.

The `uploadedFiles` in your code is translated to `null` because Grails treats `params` in the `g:remoteFuntion` WITHOUT quotes as a groovy map. So `uploadedFiles` in your code is treated as a groovy variable rather than a javascript variable in this case.

Another option is to use jquery directly rather than `g:remoteFunction`. I personally try to avoid using this tag, because in this way javascript goes inside the gsp rather than a js file. Not so good for maintenance.